# Reaction Role giver discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So i started to learn node.js and javascript a few weeks ago, in the last days i tried to make bots on discord, i wanted to make a bot that was able to do multiple things, one of this things is giving roles, i followed every step of a youtube tutorial but still it doesn't completely work, here is the index.js that i run

```
const client = new Discord.Client()

const config = require('./config.json')
const command = require('./command')
const roleClaim = require('./role-claim')

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('The client is ready!')
    })
    roleClaim(client)
});
 
client.login(config.token)
```

config and command i am 100% sure they work, the real problem is in role-claim i think

```
const firstMessage = require('./first-message')

module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelId = 'TheIdOfTheChannel'    #in the code i actually write the id of the channel

    const getEmoji = (emojiName) =>
    client.emojis.cache.find((emoji) => emoji.name === emojiName)

    const emojis = {
    civilian: 'civilian', #civilian is a customized emoji in my server
    studento: 'student'   #studento is a customized emoji in my server too
    }

    const reactions = []

    let emojiText = 'Add a reaction to claim a role\n\n'
    for (const key in emojis) {
    const emoji = getEmoji(key)
    reactions.push(emoji)

    const role = emojis[key]
    emojiText += `${emoji} = ${role}\n`
    }

    firstMessage(client, channelId, emojiText, reactions)

    const handleReaction = (reaction, user, add) => {
    if (user.id === 'IdOfTheBot') {     #in the code i actually write the id of the bot
        return
    }

    const emoji = reaction._emoji.name

    const { guild } = reaction.message

    const roleName = emojis[emoji]
    if (!roleName) {
        return
    }

    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === roleName)
    const member = guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id)

    if (add) {
        member.roles.add(role)
    } else {
        member.roles.remove(role)
    }
    }

    client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
        handleReaction(reaction, user, true)
    }
    })

    client.on('messageReactionRemove', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.message.channel.id === channelId) {
        handleReaction(reaction, user, false)
    }
    })
}
```

first-message makes the bot when runned do the role-claim.js code, a part of the code actually worked, but the problem appears with the roles, when i add the reaction the bot doesn't give me any role. I really hope somebody can help me with this bot.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work in your code ?

Comment: I would probably apply some logging to see where exactly the issues comes from. Check if the member is actrually assigned, meaning if the member is actually in the cache  or that you have to fetch it first.
In general its really useful to add some console.log in the code and see what's up.

Comment: Is there an error in the console? also, I don't see where you have declared add variable or function